# How to post data to custom user model using abstract user?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm pretty confused in this I've created a form for accepting the user model data.
Even i customised the user model data to Abstract user.

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  user_role=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
          post.first_name=request.POST.get('first_name')
          post.last_name=request.POST.get('last_name')
          post.email=request.POST.get('email')
          post.username=request.POST.get('user')
          post.password=make_password(request.POST.get('password'))
          post.user_role=1
          post.save()
```

while posting, no data is passed ,it's totally null

and when tried

```
print(post.user_role)
```

it says user has no attribute user_role

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You’ve created an abstract User, but you’re still using the default User provided by django and attempting to use a field in the abstract user.

Comment: Then how should I write in view the same way I want?

Comment: Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project make sure to import the AbstractUser you created when using it In a view and make sure it is set as your AUTH_USER_MODEL in your settings.py

Comment: Whether to add `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.myuser'` in `settings.py`.  [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: I've already done this

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing your User model, but Django's built-in User model.
In your `views.py`, change:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

to:

```
from .models import User
```

Comment: But the user model I created is part of Django user model as I've extended the deafult user model??

Comment: It is, but you are not using it. As mentioned above, go over the [official documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)

Comment: Then how I'm going to access the default user model as some fields like username, first_name etc. Is defined there whereas some  in the user model extend there is only one field.